# Organize Chef attributes in different directories

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I am trying to organize my attributes files by directory with in the attributes directory. I would look like this:

```
attributes
    -Production
        -file1.rb
        -file2.rb
    -Stage
        -file1.rb
        -file2.rb
    -Development
        -file1.rb
        -file2.rb
```

When putting the different attribute files in the directories, Chef doesnt pick them up. Is there a way to make Chef look in all directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a thing, and even using multiple files might not do what you expect. Remember that *all* attribute files are always loaded. Segmenting them into multiple files is just for readability at best, and I don't recommend it. In fact if you're using Chef 13, we got rid of the directory entirely and you can just use `mycookbooks/attributes.rb`.

Comment: I wanted to make it easier to find the different attributes (readability) as you said. Can you explain more why you do not recommend it?

Comment: Because a lot of people get the mistaken impression that only one of the files will be used, like how recipes work. If you have so many attributes that putting them in one file is too hard, you probably have too many attributes.

Comment: I have a recipe that will run through ~50 domains, each having different attribute values. The file in the end will come out to be ~600 lines of attributes. Would this be considered too many or normal?

Comment: That doesn't sound like something that should be in node attributes. Only things that actually vary should use them.

Comment: I need that amount for each domain to create them using a template

Comment: Put the data somewhere else, like in the recipe or in a data bag or some other API.